# How do you transform variable length arrays of objects into something friendly to machine learning algorithms?

Tags: json, machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis, weka

I'm trying to run several clustering and classification algorithms on a data set coming from a video-game market for my final project. I receive a massive series of objects in JSON, each with its own price and several other features. However, one of the fields in this JSON is an array of mods present on the item, like so:

```
"mods": [
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "{0}% increased Elemental Damage with Weapons",
    "value0": 31,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "+{0} to Armour",
    "value0": 234,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "+{0} to maximum Life",
    "value0": 93,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "+{0}% to Fire Resistance",
    "value0": 27,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "+{0}% to Cold Resistance",
    "value0": 25,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "{0}% increased Physical Damage",
    "value0": 24,
    "type": "IMPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "+{0}% to Lightning Resistance",
    "value0": 25,
    "type": "CRAFTED"
  }
],
```

Note this is just one of round 4 million examples in my data and I happened to randomly choose one with nothing present in the value1, 2 or 3 fields, but they are used.

The array is of **variable length**, it has a **maximum of 10 objects** and every object has the **same 6 fields** (60 total variables, including the missing objects). But much more importantly, all objects are interchangeable - their order does not matter at all.

I am trying to store this structure as attributes friendly to machine learning algorithms. If I store 60 attributes and fill the ones not present with a default, for example, ML algorithms might pick up on the fact that if you have a certain object in positions 0-5 in that array it is more valuable than if you have it in positions 6-11, and this is NOT the case. Is there a standard way to solve this problem?

Full JSON object as requested in comments:

```
"_source": {
"owner": "gogodvd",
"corrupted": false,
"mods": [
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "{0}% increased Evasion and Energy Shield",
    "value0": 121,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "{0}% increased Rarity of Items found",
    "value0": 9,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "+{0}% to Cold Resistance",
    "value0": 28,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "+{0}% to Lightning Resistance",
    "value0": 40,
    "type": "EXPLICIT"
  },
  {
    "value2": 0,
    "value1": 0,
    "value3": 0,
    "name": "+{0} to maximum Energy Shield",
    "value0": 14,
    "type": "CRAFTED"
  }
],
"added": "2017-05-17T20:04:09.484Z",
"ilvl": 84,
"mods.count": 5,
"talismanTier": 0,
"quality": 0,
"mirrored": false,
"identified": true,
"price": 10,
"name": "Doom Shelter",
"sockets": {
  "redSockets": 0,
  "largestGroup": 2,
  "greenSockets": 2,
  "totalSockets": 3,
  "blueSockets": 1
},
"rarity": 2,
"base": "Deicide Mask"
```

}

Comment: there is no shortcut. you'd need to convert this array into a number or string.  how does your typical json object look like, incl mods? pls post. if they are mostly numbers / nominal data, convert this array into a num. If they are mostly text, convert it into a word strings.

Comment: eg, you can add all value0s, value1s, value2s and value3s and see their relationship with class distribution. "type" is nominal data. for "name" strings, see if you can extract nominal data which has good match for class distribution. you can also add all "name" strings, convert into a vector and see if it has a good class distribution.

Comment: There is an entire ML Branch which is concerned with such kind of Problems. It is called Statistical relational learning. It has it's merits but requires a lot of manual modelling efforts just like (other) Graphical models. Nevertheless, you could also use some kind of recurrent structure which learns a latent representation encoding the essence of these values.
To be able to help you, however, the central question is what kind algorithm/tooling you'd use if the mentioned problem wouldn't exists.

Comment: Hi @CAFEBABE I'll keep in mind SRL, thanks for the pointer. If the mentioned problem did not exist I'd ideally like to be able to pass the data of one of an object for which the price is unknown and predict it using a classifier. I'm a bit of an ML noob so feel free to suggest other approaches.

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti do you mean hashing my entire array into one numerical field? I suppose it can be done but no idea how to go about it. I've edited the post to include a full object as requested.

Comment: thanks. your data is great. i'd suggest to go ahead ignoring mods data altogether. note down your results. follow my advice in 2nd comment, learn classification just using this attribute. if you're not able to extract nominal data out of "name" fields, then take them out, join all strings, convert into a vector and do classification. BTW, all these woes will go away if you're using NNs as they learn their features on their own.

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti I would be happy to use neural networks, but one of the objectives of the project is to try not to as they are a bit of a black box and after all we are looking to identify exactly what makes an item valuable. If you are interested in seeing the first page of data before preprocessing, check out pathofexile.com/api/public-stash-tabs. Disastrous.

Comment: Ha Ha if only I could make anything out of it.